# Find a distribution given recursive relationship between moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-problem

Let's say I have a continuous random variable $0\le X<\infty$ and I know it has first raw moment $m_1=\alpha$, and subsequent moments are defined recursively as:

$$m_{n+1}=(1+\beta n)\alpha m_n$$

for some positive constants $\alpha$, $\beta$. The $n$th raw moment is thus:

$$m_n=\alpha^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+\beta i)$$

What is the RV's distribution?

Comment: I guess the raw moments already define the MGF, and hence the distribution, of the distribution?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Let $f_{0}(z)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}z^{-1}\exp\bigl(-(\log z)^{2}/2\bigr)$ be the lognormal density. For $k\geq1$, let $f_{k}(z)=f_{0}(z)\bigl(1+\sin(2\pi\log z)/k\bigr)$ which is still a density. Then $\mathbb{E}[Z_{k}^{n}]=\exp(n^{2}/2)$ for all $n\geq1$, means $\{Z_{k}\}$ have all raw moments equal, yet with different distributions.

Comment: @Q9y5 fascinating! Do you have a source for it? Would love to look into it

Comment: @BenjaminWang This example is from Heyde (1963) *"On a property of the lognormal distribution."*